# Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'User': lastName, firstName, nickName, img, and 6 more

Tags: node.js, typescript

this is my code

```
enum UserGender {
  MALE = "MALE",
  FEMALE = "FEMALE",
  OTHER = "OTHER",
}

enum UserRegistrationStatus {
  ACTIVE = "ACTIVE",
  UNACTIVE = "UNACTIVE",
}

interface User {
  lastName: string;
  firstName: string;
  nickName: string;
  img: string;
  email: string;
  gender: UserGender;
  age: string;
  salt: string;
  password: string;
  registrationStatus: UserRegistrationStatus;
}


const user: User | null = Object.values(
    (
      await db
        .ref(`/users`)
        .orderByChild(`email`)
        .equalTo(email)
        .limitToFirst(1)
        .once("value")
    ).val()
  )[0];
```

I get this error

***Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'User': lastName, firstName, nickName, img,and 6 more.***

What am I doing wrong. How do I fix it ?

Comment: Looks like a Firebase question. On what line are you getting this error?

Comment: @user2369284 const user